# Desktop and web application Single sign-on

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application, single-sign-on, cas

I'm thinking about a SSO architecture for my company and I found very interesting CAS. I have quite clear the features available while using it in Web Applications. Instead, I didn't understand very well a possible CAS employement with desktop application (C# or Swing). Now we have a lot of web application and desktop applications and we want to manage an unique point of authentication for all. 
In your opinion, is it possible to achieve using CAS? Do you have some advices?

Comment: @John Saunders http://www.jasig.org/cas (Central Authentication Service).

Comment: Central Authentication Service

Comment: I only know CAS from a project where it was used and it needed some tweaks to get it working for us. I tend to more favor SAML/WS-* based solution but it depends on your needs. If yoor looking for SSO integration on a windows based infra ADFS2.0 is a candidate. On linux the options are broader where I know the Novell stuff will work in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on CAS's design, you can use it with a standalone app for authentication, but you will not be able to participate with the SSO abilities.

There are a couple of ways you can interact w/ cas from a standalone app.  You can either 'impersonate' a browser, and send and parse http requests and responses in an attempt to behave as the login page.

Alternatively, and likely cleaner, you can use CAS's RESTful apis: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/RESTful+API

I've not actually done this in a standalone app, but I've read posts from people doing the http 'scraping', and based on the link above, it really seems it wouldn't be too hard to do from an app that has a decent networking library.

Comment: At the end, I followed the CAS's RESTful API approach to log in through C# desktop apps.